# Expand div height to it's child (iframe)

Tags: html, css

I want to add a `border-radius` to my iframe but it's not working on Chrome. I read that I need to wrap the iframe in a div.

I don't want to set the height in the wrapper, I want it to adjust to the iframe height.

My styles:

```
.wrapper {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 120px; /* I DON"T WANT TO SET THE HEIGHT IN THE WRAPPER */
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 23px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}
```

I've been trying but I couldn't make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/qas34dum/7/

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Position the DIV instead of the iframe: https://jsfiddle.net/qas34dum/9/

Comment: @RyanWheale you should answer this quetion. don't just comment. I think your answer is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the positioning to the wrapping DIV, allowing the iframe to determine the size:

```
.wrapper {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 12px;
  position: fixed;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 23px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

iframe {
  border: 0;
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qas34dum/9/